# android studio でrawディレクトリにmp3ファイルを入れると文字化けしたテキストファイルとして開かれる

Tags: android-studio

表題の通りです。
rawフォルダにmp3をテキストファイル扱いとしてインポートして以降、
いくら削除して新たにインポートしても、文字化けしたテキストファイルとして表示されてしまいます。

最初にインポートした際には

> Open matching files in associated application

とラジオボタンでファイルの開き方を選択する画面が出てきたのですが、
2回目以降からは出てこなくて困っています

どなたか教えてくださるととても助かります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問の意図を確認させてください。この質問は「`Android Studio`でrawディレクトリにインポートした`mp3`ファイルを`Android Studio`上で開こうとすると、テキストファイルとして開かれ、その中身が文字化けしている」という問題の解決方法を求める質問でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。その通りです！

Answer (score 1):

本家の[この質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613751/how-to-register-new-file-type-association-with-mp3)と同件のようです。

最初の「Open matching files in associated application」の選択で`.mp3`の拡張子を持つファイルを、テキストファイルとして開くように関連付けを設定しているため、２回目以降はテキストファイルとして開かれるようになっています。

この関連付けは`Android Studio`の設定によるものですので、`Android Studio`で`設定 -> エディター -> ファイルタイプ`を開き、テキストファイルとして開く拡張子として設定されている`mp3`の指定を削除してください。